# No sound on a HP Pavilion dv6 with ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound, hp-pavilion, dv6

After installation Ubuntu 12.04 in my hp pavilion dv6 machine sound system is not working.
commands like

```
gksudo gedit  /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
killall pulseaudio  sudo alsa force-reload  pulseaudio -D
sudo alsa force-reload
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libasound2
gksudo gedit  /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
killall pulseaudio  sudo alsa force-reload  pulseaudio -D
gksudo gedit  /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

had tried as revealed from forum's discussion. Inspite of all these its not working.

Answer (score 0):

This works!  Just close the test files that open to proceed to the next step.  then turn your volume on the HP pavilion up at the bar above the keyboard.  It starts at mute.